# How to use callbacks in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, std-function

I am trying to use callbacks in c++ using `std::function`. I have two files, `mainwindow.cpp` and `tcpclient.cpp`. A member function of `mainwindow` is passed to `tcpclient` in order call the passed function when a certain even occurs.

`mainwindow.h`

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void connectedToServer(int errorCode);

    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_connectButton_clicked();
    TCPClient *tcpClient_;
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    tcpClient_ = &TCPClient("localhost", ui->portText->text(), ui->consoleText, this->connectedToServer)
}
```

`tcpclient.h`

```
#ifndef TCPCLIENTH
#define TCPCLIENTH

#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QString>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <functional>
#include <tcpclientbadresponse.h>
#include <tcpclientserverdisconnected.h>


class TCPClient : public QTcpSocket
{
public:
    TCPClient(QString hostName, int port, QString clientID, QTextEdit *consoleText,
              std::function<void(int)> *onCompletionCallback);
    void connectToServer(QString requestType, QJsonDocument requestJson);
    QJsonDocument getResponse() const;

private:
    std::function<void(int)> onCompletionCallback;


};

#endif // TCPCLIENTH
```

`tcpclient.cpp`

```
#include "tcpclient.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <exception>


TCPClient::TCPClient(QString hostName, int port, QString clientID, QTextEdit *consoleText,
                     std::function<void(int)> *onCompletionCallback)
: hostName_(hostName),
  port_(port),
  clientID_(clientID),
  consoleText_(consoleText),
  onCompletionCallback(onCompletionCallback)
{
    this->connectionStatus_ = TCPClient::CONNECTION_STATUS::IDLE;
    qDebug() << "Client " << clientID_ << " created";
}
```

I get the following error

> non static member function must be called

What does this error mean? How do I use `std::function` to pass callbacks?

EDIT: As per the first comment, I have removed code parts not related to this question improve clarity.

Comment: I agree. I have removed unrelated code parts to improve clarity. I will keep this in mind when posting in the future. Thanks for providing reasons for you down vote.

Comment: It would help if you specified which line generates that error. I think I see one problem thought I'm not sure if it would cause that error. The onCompletionCallback parameter of your constructor is a `pointer to std::function<void(int)>` so assigning it to an object of type `std::function<void(int)>` without dereferencing is not what you want. Either remove the * from the parameter or adjust the initialization to `onCompletionCallback(*onCompletionCallback)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from Sam Varshavachik's answer the solution to error is to make `void onCompletionCallback(int)` a `static` member function

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the shown code. At least two problems are apparent: the one that's causing the compilation error at issue and a second one, with the compilation error set aside, will result in undefined behavior, and pretty much a guaranteed crash.

A `std::function` class member gets declared as follows:

```
std::function<void(int)> onCompletionCallback;
```

This declaration seems to be correct, but an attempt to initialize this class member is as follows:

```
TCPClient::TCPClient(/* ... */
     std::function<void(int)> *onCompletionCallback)
: /* ... */
  onCompletionCallback(onCompletionCallback)
```

The parameter to the constructor is a pointer to this `std::function`, and attempt is made to initialize this `std::function` from a pointer to the `std::function`.

This will not compile for the same exact reason why you will not be able to compile anything that gets declared as

```
int someClassmember;
```

And then initialized like

```
someConstructor(int *someClassmember)
   : someClassmember(someClassmember)
```

You can't initialize an `int` from a pointer to `int`. Similarly, you cannot initialize a `std::function` from a pointer to the `std::function`. The fix should be obvious. The constructor's parameter should not be a pointer; and, optimally, it should be declared as a `const std::function<...> &parameter`, a `const` reference.

The second problem is in `MainWindow`'s constructor:

```
tcpClient_ = &TCPClient( /* ... */ )
```

This expression, "TCPClient( ... )", constructs a temporary object. This temporary object gets destroyed immediately after the evaluation of the complete expression.

This results in this expression saving a pointer to a temporary object that gets destroyed immediately. Subsequent dereferencing of this pointer results in a wild pointer dereference, and pretty much a guaranteed crash. Once you fix your compilation error, you will discover that your code will horribly crash, until you fix this as well.

Most modern compilers are smart enough to detect this frequent kind of a logical bug, and issue a warning. If your compiler is also issuing a warning on this line, this is a valuable lesson not to ignore compiler diagnostics, even if the compiler still compiles the resulting code. Compilers' warning messages are nearly always issued for a good reason, and should not be ignored.

Comment: Hey Sam. Thank you very much for taking your time to give me a detailed answer. It was really helpful. Thanks again, I am not so advanced c++ coder, but getting insights from people like you is really helping me to learn.

Comment: Hey Sam, I fixed the code as you advised (I modified the `constructor` of `TCPClient` to accept a `const` reference to the callback function. But I still get the error `reference to a non-static member function must be called`. Any thoughts?

Comment: You asked for a thought, here's one: experienced C++ coders do not write a large pile of code first, and then try to compile the whole thing. A large amount of code always starts out small. A little bit is written, compiled and tested. Then a little bit more is written, and compiled and tested again. This way, one has to deal with only a few errors at a time. This is why I wrote "at least two problems are apparent". Fixing the obvious problems would likely make others come to light. Take what you have now, prepare a new [mcve], and post a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: But you should prove in your new question that you tried to understand and fix your compilation errors yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I think your approach writing small units of code and testing them is really good and useful. I am gonna use that approach. Anyway I fixed my problem thanks.